# jqueryUI - drag item to multiple lists

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

My scenario is that I have a list of peoples names contained as list items and I want to be able to drag those names into boxes.  I got this part working through jqueryUI, but my issue is that when the name is dragged to the box, I don't want it to be moved out of the original list because a person can be in more than one list.

I assume the issue is that I am using .appendTo instead of .add, but it's clearly not as simple as just switching .appendTo to .add

`$( this ).appendTo( $list ).show( "slow" );`

Entire code:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable().disableSelection();

    var $tabs = $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    var $tab_items = $( "ul:first li", $tabs ).droppable({
        accept: ".connectedSortable li",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var $item = $( this );
            var $list = $( $item.find( "a" ).attr( "href" ) )
                .find( ".connectedSortable" );

            ui.draggable.hide( "slow", function() {

                $( this ).appendTo( $list ).show( "slow" );



            });
        }
    });
});
```

Please see the fiddle below for the working example and HTML markup.
http://jsfiddle.net/sXRKd/1/

Gracias!

Comment: When you are dropped one person into other, it must be avail in both place. That's what you wanted, am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope, When you are dropped one person into other, it must be avail in both place. For example when you drop `josh mondie` into `Close Friends` it must to avail in both `All Friends` and also `Close Friends`.

Take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXRKd/6/), where it's working fine.

Code,

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
      var $droppableId = $("a", this).attr("href");
      var $newList = $(".connectedSortable", $droppableId);

      ui.draggable.hide("slow", function () {
        $newList.append(ui.draggable.clone().show());
      });
      ui.draggable.show("slow");
    }
```